# PreviewKeyDown not firing for Tab and Arrow keys in ElementHost

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have a WPF window in a Winforms ElementHost.  The KeyDown and PreviewKeyDown events are not firing for the Tab and arrow keys on my Window.

KeyUp and PreviewKeyUp seem to work fine, as does PreviewKeyDown for most other keys, like: A-Z, 0-9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that my Window was opened from a Winforms application.
The **ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop()** method solved my problem.

```
var myWindow = new MyWindow();
ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(myWindow);
myWindow.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I was having a hard time figuring out why my WPF window was not receiving arrow key events. This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks