# C# button up/down/left/right not detected

Tags: c#, wpf

A week ago I used this for detecting the `up/down/left/right keys` in my 
wpf application:

```
private void Invaders_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString());
    switch (e.KeyCode.ToString())
    {
        case "Up":
            MessageBox.Show("Up");
            break;
        case "Down":
            MessageBox.Show("Down");
            break;
        case "Left":
            MessageBox.Show("Left");
            break;
        case "Right":
            MessageBox.Show("Right");
            break;
    }
}
```

But today I started a new application and this does not work anymore? It detects everything except `up/down/left/right`. What could be going on here?

Comment: Have you bind the eventhandler to the Event definition?

Comment: In your switch statement, you can remove `.ToString()` from `e.KeyCode.ToString()` and use the KeyCodes as cases accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textbox Keydown event not firing when arrow key press](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931399/textbox-keydown-event-not-firing-when-arrow-key-press)

Comment: Try PreviewKeyDown instead.

Comment: Yes eventhandler is set correct.

Comment: Set a break point in the event handler. Confirm you can hit it. Check the value of the key code.

Comment: Please put your xaml also.  You get any error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link Invaders_PreviewKeyDown to KeyDown event of your buttons. Don't using string for check. That code should is:

```
private void Invaders_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString());
     switch (e.KeyCode)
     {
        case Keys.Up:
           MessageBox.Show("Up");
           break;
        case Keys.Down:
           MessageBox.Show("Down");
           break;
        case Keys.Left:
          MessageBox.Show("Left");
          break;
        case Keys.Right:
          MessageBox.Show("Right");
        break;
        default:
          // Do something with default
          break;
     }
}
```