# WPF TreeView KeyBinding Ctrl + Down

Tags: wpf, treeview, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to handle Ctrl + Down in a treeview as a custom shortcut. I've tried the following code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTreeIssue.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTreeIssue"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    x:Name="_this">
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this}">
    <TreeView>
        <TreeView.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding
                Key="Down" Modifiers="Ctrl"
                Command="{Binding ControlDownCommand}" />
            <KeyBinding
                Key="A"
                Command="{Binding ControlDownCommand}" />
        </TreeView.InputBindings>

        <TreeViewItem Header="Level 1" IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Level 2.1" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Level 2.2" IsExpanded="True">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Level 3.1" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Level 3.2" />
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Level 2.3" />
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ICommand ControlDownCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand<KeyBinding>(x => OnControlDown(x));
        }
    }

    private void OnControlDown(KeyBinding keyBinding)
    {
        Console.Write("HELLO");
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

RelayCommand is a basic ReplayCommand as seen here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/

I've added KeyBindings for both `Ctrl-Down` & `A`. The `A` shortcut works just fine, but Ctrl-Down does not work.

I've tried removing the Ctrl modifier and the down shortcut still does not work (it moves the selected tree item, which makes sense). Interestly, the down shortcut DOES work if you navigate to the last item in the treeview and hit down (Ctrl-down does not work in that instance).

Any suggestions as to how I can get the Ctrl-Down KeyBinding to work on my TreeView?

Edit: I've also tried overriding the TreeView's OnKeyDown and OnPreviewKeyDown methods with no luck. See below:

```
public class CustomTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Down arrow");
            if ((e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl) || e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TEST");
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Down arrow");
            if ((e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl) || e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TEST");
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

If I hold the Ctrl key & press down the line `Console.WriteLine("Down arrow");` never gets hit (down arrow event is not sent). If I just press down, the line gets hit but the ctrl modifier is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a code in `TreeView` control which handles Ctrl+Down so your binding is not working as the keys event is already processed. You need to override `OnKeyDown` on `TreeView` to do something of your own.

**Update**: Here is a tested sample

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
            {
                if (System.Windows.Input.Key.Down == e.Key)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Ctlr+Down");
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }

            if (!e.Handled)
            {
                base.OnKeyDown(e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I gave this a try but the OnKeyDown event does not fire for the down arrow key. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931399/textbox-keydown-event-not-firing-when-arrow-key-press?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa I need to use `PreviewKeyDown` to handle arrow keys, which does fire for Down itself, but not if down + ctrl are pressed. I may need to use a combination of preview/up/down and track state maybe.

Comment: You need to have `OnKeyDown` method overridden in the control as the event is fired only if a key is not handled. Or, as you've said, `PreviewXXX` is the place. You may want to use `Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control)` to check state of Control key.

Comment: Tried overriding (see update to question) - I can only seem to access EITHER the Ctrl key or the down key.... not both at once :S

Comment: Have you tried static property `Keyboard.Modifiers` instead of `KeyboardDevice`?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is before that.. If I am holding Ctrl down neither the OnpreviewKeyDown or OnKeyDown events make it past `if (e.Key == Key.Down)` (they fire once for the ctrl key, then do not fire again for the down key until I let go of ctrl).

Comment: @1969877, see update - checked a second ago and got that `Ctrl+Down` message in Output window. XAML is yours, without `InputBinding` part

Comment: Ahhhhh, your absolutely correct. Once I removed the `InputBinding` section it worked like a charm.