# How to detect home and end keys in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, keydown

I have a WPF window with a DataGrid control that has a KeyDown event.

When I press Home or End, I don't get any event triggered. Why is that? How can I fix it?

When I press Home I want to show the first row, and End to show the last row.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void SetField<T> ( ref T field, T value, string propertyName )
        {
            if ( !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals ( field, value ) )
            {
                field = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke ( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs ( propertyName ) );
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Coin> _coins;
        public ObservableCollection<Coin> Coins { get => _coins; set => SetField ( ref _coins, value, nameof ( _coins ) ); }
        public ICollectionView CollectionView;

        public MainWindow ( )
        {
            this.Coins = new ObservableCollection<Coin> ( );
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i )
                this.Coins.Add ( new Coin ( "Coin 1", i ) );

            this.DataContext = this;

            InitializeComponent ( );

            this.KeyDown += MainWindow_KeyDown;
        }

        void MainWindow_KeyDown ( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( e.Key );
        }
    }

    public class Coin
    {
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public int PNL { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush Color2 { get; set; }

        public Coin ( string symbol, int pnl )
        {
            this.Symbol = symbol;
            this.PNL = pnl;

            Random rnd = new Random ( );
            Color c = Color.FromRgb ( ( byte ) rnd.Next ( 256 ), ( byte ) rnd.Next ( 256 ), ( byte ) rnd.Next ( 256 ) );

            this.Color2 = new SolidColorBrush ( c );
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Name="myMainWindow"
    SizeToContent="Width"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="Profit Tracker"
    Topmost="True"
    Height="426">

    <Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#1e90ff"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnAlarmStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#000000"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF" />
            <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="RowStyleWithAlternation" TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#141414"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#141414"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#282828"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,0,0,0" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1e90ff" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>-->
                </Trigger>



                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="4"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#006400" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0">
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="#75001D" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Coins}" IsLiveSortingRequested="True" x:Key="MyKey" />

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyKey}}" SelectionMode="Single" GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyleWithAlternation}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="PNL" Width="60" SortMemberPath="Balance.UnitPrice" Binding="{Binding Path=PNL}" />

                <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}" CanUserSort="False"/>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Price" Width="60" SortMemberPath="Price">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="#241C59" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Background="#2D255B">
                                        <Border BorderBrush="#206fb6" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="2" ClipToBounds="True" Margin="-1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                            <Border.Effect>
                                                <BlurEffect Radius="10"/>
                                            </Border.Effect>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0." Background="#69ABDB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="30">
                                        <Border BorderBrush="#38e2ff" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2" ClipToBounds="False">
                                            <Border.Effect>
                                                <BlurEffect Radius="5"/>
                                            </Border.Effect>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="25%" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Vol BTC/h" Width="30" SortMemberPath="LastHourVolumeInBtc">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="ABCDE" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Vol BTC/h" Width="40">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <ProgressBar Value="0.3" Minimum="0" Maximum="1"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="12345" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Net BTC/m" Width="60"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you show your code for `MainWindow.xaml`? Hopefully you have this routine defined in this window, otherwise it will not be hit.

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: Other keys fire like L 1 2 3 F5 etc.

Comment: Interesting, my Home and End fire off just fine. Create a new WPF project, slap a datagrid on it and try it, does it work?

Comment: But did you have a data grid view control covering the window? Maybe that's blocking the Home and End with its hard coded functions.

Comment: Yes, the DataGrid control filled the whole window.

Comment: That's strange i will investigate why it doesnt do anything in my case then, coz if I press ctrl+Home then it just prints RightCtrl

Comment: I found from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931399/textbox-keydown-event-not-firing-when-arrow-key-press It works when I use the preview event handler instead.

Comment: good find, I honestly thought about the preview, but I was curious as to why just the normal `KeyDown` event worked fine for me and not for you... It still makes me think something else is wrong though.

Comment: In wpf many events are [routed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview?#routing-strategies). The [KeyDown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.keydown) event is specifically *bubbling*, means it will progress from child to it's parent all the way up *until handled*. Something on the way handles this event, that's why you don't receive it in window event handler. Typical solution would be to use *tunneling* event - [PreviewKeyDown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown).

Comment: I think it's possible. I have to dive deeper but not sure I didn't customize much especially wrt to key presses.

Comment: @Sinatr can I find out what's handling it?

Comment: @JoanVenge, do you really need to know it? Its one of the parents of child with keyboard focus (make sure to understand [focus in wpf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/focus-overview) too). Show xaml if you need to know.

Comment: @Sinatr I guess not but if I know maybe I can prevent it to handle those keys.

Comment: Hi all, I updated the code with my reusable test code and if you run it, you will see that Home and End doesn't fire, but other keys do. So feel free to check and play around and see if you can find the issue. Anyway I will use preview event but i wanted to update everyone.

Answer (score 0):

For consistency, you would be best to declare your own class in-code and subclass that of the DataGrid (what your application is probably using anyhow).  Then add the key press capture test to that.  This way, all you would have to do is change the class put into your WPF window, you would change to YOUR class and have all embedded throughout wherever applied.

Here is a sample from what I have tested.

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public MyDataGrid()
    {
        KeyUp += MyDataGrid_KeyUp;
    }

    private void MyDataGrid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch( e.Key )
        {
            case Key.Home:
                // do what on the home...
                break;

            case Key.End:
                // do what on the end key
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your WPF xaml

at the top of your form, you would need to include your namespace for access to the class such as

```
xmlns:MyApp="clr-namespace:MyApp"
```

Then, within the body of the window details where you have your data grid, just change from:

```
<DataGrid blah blah blah >
    
</DataGrid>
```

change to

```
<MyApp:MyDataGrid blah blah blah>

</MyApp:MyDataGrid>
```

The good thing here is now you have a central location for your grid customization such as when data bindings/context may get changed, you can hook into and adjust whatever else you may want.  Add additional key hooks once and they would be applied globally where you use in your app.

Additionally, the keypresses only on the grid would be captured and not everywhere within your app.

Comment: The event the OP is handling is in the `Window` not a `DataGrid`, although I do agree about sub classing to keep the customizations in a central location.

Comment: @Codexer, I think that is just how he was INTERPRETING he wanted but may not have known better, as you see and understand from my offer.  Why try to capture all keypresses on every control the WINDOW.  Only capture when on the data grid focus.

Comment: In WPF we rarely need to subclass controls, especially for such small tasks. Not downvoting, but highly not recommending going this path unless custom control functionality is really require making a custom control. A much better (reusable and centralized) approach is to use attached behavior.

Comment: @Sinatr, appreciate and respect the response but was never impressed with the behavior option in my app development.